# Fastest way to invoke one AWS API Gateway from another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have 2 AWS API Gateway deployed like so:

API1 --> api1.mydomain.com (Back end integration Lambda1)

API2 --> api2.mydomain.com (Back end integration Lambda2)

While API1 and API2 can be invoked from different services there are use cases where API1 also invokes API2.

However, as of today the invocation is through simple HTTP client.
Which means;
Lambda1 uses Aapche HTTP client to invoke "api1.mydomain.com".

**Question**
Is there a faster way to invoke API2 from Lambda1 without impacting clients who call API1 or API2 over the internet?
My understanding is when Lambda1 invokes "api1.mydomain.com", it does so by following the public internet.

My artifacts API1, API2, Lambda1 and Lambda2 are all on the same AWS Account and in the same VPC\AWS Region.
I am trying to see if I can reduce the network time for the invocation where artifacts in the same region do not have to do the public internet roundtrip.

Comment: since it sounds like your decision making logic is within lambda, there isnt much you can do. I would recommend determining the path that would force API1 to call API2, then create and API Gateway Endpoint w/ integration type HTTP. if you require some transformation of data, look into mapping templates w/ api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a Private Endpoint

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

Set up one of these for your API2, and all traffic to it will be routed through the private interface endpoint in your VPC, giving you the communication efficiency you're looking for

Comment: Thanks @AndyK But my requirement also is that API2 should also be accessible through IG as well.
The problem is, private apigateway doesn't allow public access. Essentially I require a dual behavior. I had looked at private api gateway previously. Does it support this behavior now?